# Get Drawable from image view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

When I do the clip drawable example described in [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Clip) document ImageView.getDrawable always return null. Can anyone pls help me?

In MainActivity.java onCreate

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ImageView imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        ClipDrawable drawable = (ClipDrawable) imageview.getDrawable();
        drawable.setLevel(drawable.getLevel() + 1000); //Line number 21
    }
```

Logcat

```
 02-04 12:16:31.156: E/AndroidRuntime(4611): FATAL EXCEPTION: main02-04 12:16:31.156: E/AndroidRuntime(4611): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

02-04 12:16:31.156: E/AndroidRuntime(4611):      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)

02-04 12:16:31.156: E/AndroidRuntime(4611):      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)

02-04 12:16:31.156: E/AndroidRuntime(4611):      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)

02-04 12:16:31.156: E/AndroidRuntime(4611):      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)

02-04 12:16:31.156: E/AndroidRuntime(4611):      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

02-04 12:16:31.156: E/AndroidRuntime(4611):      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)

02-04 12:16:31.156: E/AndroidRuntime(4611):      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)

02-04 12:16:31.156: E/AndroidRuntime(4611):      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

02-04 12:16:31.156: E/AndroidRuntime(4611):      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)

02-04 12:16:31.156: E/AndroidRuntime(4611):      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)

02-04 12:16:31.156: E/AndroidRuntime(4611):      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)

02-04 12:16:31.156: E/AndroidRuntime(4611):      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

02-04 12:16:31.156: E/AndroidRuntime(4611): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

02-04 12:16:31.156: E/AndroidRuntime(4611):      at com.example.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)

02-04 12:16:31.156: E/AndroidRuntime(4611):      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)

02-04 12:16:31.156: E/AndroidRuntime(4611):      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)

02-04 12:16:31.156: E/AndroidRuntime(4611):      ... 11 more
```

Comment: share your logcat
also your piece of code

Comment: @Dinesh you want to take the snapshot of imageview right??

Comment: @UsmanKurd i have added log-cat output

Comment: @TGMCians no i just exploring clip drawable

Comment: what is on line 21 in `MainActivity.java`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to override onWindowsFocusChanged()

```
 @Override
 public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasWindowFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasWindowFocus);
   ClipDrawable drawable = (ClipDrawable) imageview.getBackground();
    drawable.setLevel(drawable.getLevel() + 1000); //Line number 21
 }
```

the imageView was not yet displayed properly when you tried to get its value(drawable image).
onWindowsFocusChanged()  will inform the user that the view has been loaded already that's the time you can get its data.

Comment: I updated my code above,  instead of `imageview.getDrawable` changed to `image.getBackground()`.

Comment: thanks @SheSmile It's works fine i have add a button in button onclick i have do the drawable.setLevel

Answer (score 1):

May be you will get `null drawable` so this error will occure.

First `set`  any `image` to `ImageView` so you will get Drawable.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ImageView imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        imageview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon);
        ClipDrawable drawable = (ClipDrawable) imageview.getDrawable();
        if(drawable != null){
        drawable.setLevel(drawable.getLevel() + 1000); //Line number 21
        }
    }
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Clip look this link for clip drawable example i do the same in image i didn't give the src instead of i gave the background clip drawable

Comment: android:background="@drawable/clip" have you set this?

Answer (score 1):

This is an easy approach if you can use the view's id member variable: just store the R.drawable id using v.setId().  Then get it back with v.getId().

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers till now is correct

The issue here is that in the image view the drawable is attached using `android:background="@drawable/clip"` and it is retrieved using `ClipDrawable drawable = (ClipDrawable) imageview.getDrawable();`

Fixes:

Change the imageview xml

`android:background="@drawable/clip"` -> `android:src="@drawable/clip"`

**OR**

Change the button callback code

`ClipDrawable drawable = (ClipDrawable) imageview.getDrawable();` -> `ClipDrawable drawable = (ClipDrawable) imageview.getBackground();`

**Don't change both, otherwise the problem will get created again. Change any one.**